# How to access and initialize components of simd types?

Tags: objective-c, simd

I have some variables of type simd_float3 and simd_float4x4.
How do I access the single components for example the y component of the float3?

How do I initialize a float4x4 when i have an array that consists of 16 floats?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `simd_matrix()`; for example:

```
_transform = simd_matrix(
    (simd_float4){ sxc,     -sxs,   0.0f,   0.0f },
    (simd_float4){ sys,     syc,    0.0f,   0.0f },
    (simd_float4){ 0.0f,    0.0f,   1.0f,   0.0f },
    (simd_float4){ tx,      ty,     0.0f,   1.0f }
);
```

Related functions are `simd_make_float2(0.0f, 0.0f)`, etc.

You access the elements as if they were an array; `x` is `[0]`, `y` is `[1]`, etc.

[Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/simd/simd_float3?language=objc).

Comment: I am using `simd_make_float3` to make a vector already, but i cannot access the single elements by using dot notation with `.x` for example. i get a compiler error

Comment: @Raildex I was wrong about the `.x`, `.y`, etc.  Use array element syntax instead (`[0]`, etc).

Comment: okay it looks like accessing with the array syntax seems to work.
Is it possible to use memcpy to transfer my 16 float array into float4x4?

Comment: @Raildex Yeah why not.

Comment: @Raildex Make sure you understand how the row- or column-major matrix representation works though.  You might be better off building the matrix a row at a time (`simd_matrix_from_rows()`) or a column at a time (`simd_matrix()`).